# Play Store - "An unexpected error has occurred. Please try again later."

Tags: google-play-store

I've been having this issue since I bought my S7 Edge over a week ago. I am unable to add a payment method or do anything involving payments on both my phone and play.google.com.

When trying to add a payment method, or even redeem a gift card, via play.google.com I get this:

[image]

And when I try adding a payment method via my phone I get "We couldn't complete your request. Please retry or try again later." regardless of when or how many times I try.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So it turns out the Google Organisation my Google Account was managed by had Google Payments (formerly Google Wallet) disabled for all users; after enabling it, everything works perfectly.

Comment: Amazingly correct, and raspberries to Google for a terrible, unhelpful error message!

Comment: Wonderful.....for YOU. Not very helpful, however, unless you give a TINY bit of information about how you "enabled" it.

Comment: @MichaelScott This is for Google for business only but if you have that then go to admin.google.com and choose apps. Payments should be in the list. Enable or disable with the three vertical dots on the right.

Answer (score 0):

You need to clear cache for Google play store and Google play service. If that didn't solve it then you have to delete both and reinstall it. Then try again.

If the above option didn't work,  go to Settings/Accounts/Google, Select your gmail and turn off sync. From your web browser, go to [Google Wallet](http://wallet.google.com) delete payment details and add it again. Go back to settings/Account/Google, select your gmail and click sync now. After few minutes, restart your device and try to see if the error still display.

If any of these did not work, please contact Google support or read [Payment issues](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/1267137?co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid&hl=en).

Comment: "Delete BOTH.......and reinstall IT"? What, pray-tell is.........IT?